# How to set initial value of Animate presence of Framer Motion to false in mobile view in React using hooks

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, web-deployment, framer-motion

I want the initial prop value of Animate Presence in Framer Motion set to false in a mobile device so that the animation won't take place. I have tried to create a state using useState like this and set it in useEffect.

```
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
        setIsMobile(true);
    }
}, []);



<AnimatePresence initial={isMobile ? false : true}>
  <Switch location={location} key={location.key}>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/projects/:projectId'component={ProjectPage}/>
        <Route exact path='/more/:optionId' component={Options} />
  </Switch>
```

But the problem here is that the useEffect is called after the elements render. And thus, the animations already have occurred. Is there a way to solve this. Also, I want to remove some animations in mobile devices because it's not working smoothly on mobile and mobile chrome keeps crashing after some time. It's working smoothly on the desktop. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initiate your state with that:

```
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(() => window.innerWidth < 700);
```

Better way would be using media queries, something like that https://github.com/contra/react-responsive

```
const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 720px)' })
```